# nginx large file upload gives HTTP Error 413 Request entity too large in rails

Tags: nginx, ruby-on-rails, upload

I trying to build a rails application to upload large video file which will be hosted at s3.amazonaws.com server it works fine with smaller file but gives 413 Request entity too large error for large file (around 30MB). I change my nginx configuration file and increased client_max_body_size to 4G. Still it does not work.

Can anybody help me ?

Comment: Did you restart nginx after changing your configuration?

Comment: What's in the error log?

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest looking at **all** the different places where `client_max_body_size` could be set. For example, in the server and location sections - anywhere that Nginx is pulling configuration files from.

To find *any* occurrences of `client_max_body_size`, try the following unix command from the nginx directory:

```
sudo grep -R 'client_max_body_size' ./*
```